# Implicit differentiation such that I an numerically solve an equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, implicit

If I have some function:

N(t) = N0*e^(b*t)

where b is a function of N(t).

How do i calculate dN/dt?

It gives me a recursion warning since it's just caught in a loop of substituting in N(t) into b over and over again.

Comment: Is this a Mathematica question? Mathematica uses square brackets and capital E for Euler's number.

Comment: `b is a function of N(t).` How exactly is `b` defined ? `It gives me a recursion warning` It will be better to post the full code you used so folks do not have to guess. It is strange that `b` is function of `N(t)`. Are you sure of this?

Comment: btw, watch out for using `N` in Mathematica for your own variable of your own function name, as it is an actual build in function.

Answer (score 3):

```
G = n[t] - n0 Exp[b[n[t]] t];
dG = D[G, t] /. {E^(t b[n[t]]) n0 -> n[t]};
solnt = n'[t] /. Solve[dG == 0, n'[t]][[1]] // Simplify
```

$$
\frac{n(t) b(n(t))}{1-t n(t) b'(n(t))}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way, for "algebraic" equations as opposed to "functional" equations:

```
 eqn = x y^2 == Exp[x y];
 Dt[y]/Dt[x] /. First@Solve[Dt[eqn], Dt[y]]
```

> ```
> (*  (y (-E^(x y) + y))/(x (E^(x y) - 2 y))  *)
> ```

It's "algebraic" because `y` is not expressed explicitly `y[x]`, as a function of `x`.  It was easier to type a random equation because it doesn't matter, and the OP didn't make it easy to copy.  Here, `y` is like $N$ and `x` is like $t$.

*Parameters.*
Handling constant parameters is a bit more involved since unlike `D`, `Dt` by default assumes nothing is constant.  `Dt` has the `Constants` option, but it's a bit inconvenient since `Dt` appears in four places above.  You can use `SetOptions`.

```
eqn2 = x y^2 == a Exp[k x y];

SetOptions[Dt, Constants -> {a, k}];
Dt[y]/Dt[x] /. First@Solve[Dt[eqn2], Dt[y]]
SetOptions[Dt, {}];
```

> ```
> (*  (y (-a E^(k x y) k + y))/(x (a E^(k x y) k - 2 y))  *)
> ```

Alternatives: (1) Substitute `0` for `Dt` of a parameter (what I do on the fly most times). (2) Set the `Constant` attribute on the parameters, either locally or globally.

```
Dt[y]/Dt[x] /. First@Solve[Dt[eqn2], Dt[y]] /. 
  Thread[Dt@{a, k} -> 0] // Simplify

Block[{a, k}, (* optional: clears attribute after execution *)
 SetAttributes[#, Constant] & /@ {a, k};
 Dt[y]/Dt[x] /. First@Solve[Dt[eqn2], Dt[y]]
 ]
```